# How to read an empty excel cell with xlrd in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am using xlrd for the first time. I'm using the code below, which is working perfectly as long as there is some content in the cell. But if the cell is empty, there is an error message: 
File "sheet.py", line 412, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: array index out of range

I googled this error and got several problem solving proposals, but nothing worked. Is anybody here who could help me?

This is the code that works if the cell is not empty:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('table.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('table1')
value = worksheet.cell(1, 4).value
print(value)
```

I already tried several things like

```
open_workbook(..., ragged_rows=True)
```

or

```
if  worksheet.cell_type(1, 4) != xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY and \
    worksheet.cell_type(1, 4) != xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK: 
# the cell has data
write...
```

Comment: you may check `work_sheet.nrows` and `work_sheet.ncols` firstly while using index to get the specified value

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My problem is that the file is not fully filled, so there are empty cells, but in the next row there is an entry again. Therefore it's not helpful to check the number of rows and colums, is it?

Comment: Now I got what you mean Jimmy, thanks! This works for empty cells as well: value = worksheet.row(row_number)[column_number].value